# $\int_a^b f(x)\mu(dx)$ is ambiguous if the space contains atoms

Tags: measure-theory, notation

A quick question about the notation $\int_a^b f(x)\mu(dx)$. This notation is a bit ambiguous if the measure space contains atoms right? I mean, if $a$ is an atom $(\mu(\{a\})> 0)$ then $\int_{(a,b)}f(x)\mu(dx)$ and $\int_{[a,b)}f(x)\mu(dx)$ are not the same right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes.  As you suggest, better practice is to use $\int_A$ with $A$ an unambiguous description of the set

Comment: Okay thank you!